# How to write in BigQuery to get some specifit url from GA4?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to extract data from GA4 in BigQuery with only some specifict URL.
I alredy write the code, but I dont know how to filter the data with the specifit URL only I want to extract.

```
SELECT 

  user_pseudo_id,  
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) as Date,
  event_name,
  regexp_replace((select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'page_location'), r'\?.*', '') as page_location,
  geo.region as Province,
  geo.city as City

 FROM `ga4-web-stream.analytics_396005669.events_intraday_*`
```

I only need to see some specific url like "https://www.creatve.id/", "https://www.creatve.id/jasa-pasang-atap-alderon/", "https://www.creatve.id/jasa-pasang-kanopi/"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  user_pseudo_id,  
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) AS Date,
  event_name,
  regexp_replace((SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location'), r'\?.*', '') AS page_location,
  geo.region AS Province,
  geo.city AS City
FROM `ga4-web-stream.analytics_396005669.events_intraday_*`
WHERE 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(regexp_replace((SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location'), r'\?.*', ''), r'^https://www\.creatve\.id/|https://www\.creatve\.id/jasa-pasang-atap-alderon/|https://www\.creatve\.id/jasa-pasang-kanopi/')
```